# Turn off white space highligting

Tags: sublimetext3

Following is in Preferences.sublime-settings:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/IDLE.tmTheme",
    "draw_white_space": "none"
}
```

Why is the leading white space highlighted in red/maroon? I would like to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: That color means that whatever is there is invalid. What syntax do you have the file set to? If it's not JSON, set it and see if the red goes away.

Comment: It is set to JSON and tab size is 4

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate what you're seeing - the IDLE color scheme looks fine to me in JSON files, tab-indented or space-indented. If you don't have a whole lot of customization to redo (packages, settings, etc.) you may want to try [reverting to a freshly-installed state](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html).